# how do I use current node instead of this?

Tags: javascript

JS

```
var menuBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-block');
var lenOfMenuBtn = menuBtn.length;
for (var i = 0; i < lenOfMenuBtn; i++) {
    menuBtn[i].addEventListener('click',addMenu,false);
}

function addMenu() {
    addOkFlag();
    //addToCart();
    //removeOkFlag();
}

function addOkFlag() {
    var elmnt = document.createElement('i');
    elmnt.setAttribute('class','glyphicon glyphicon-ok');
    this.appendChild(elmnt);
}
```

Error is "this.appendChild is not a function". I want to call multiple function when user click the button so I call first function where I want to add `<i>` tag in it but I don't how to pass current node from addEventListener to append this child.

Comment: You need to set *this* in *addOkFlag* when it's called from *addMenu*, which has its *this* set to the element when it's called by the handler, e.g. using call: `addOkFlag.call(this)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the clicked element to the function

```
var menuBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-block') ;
var lenOfMenuBtn = menuBtn.length ;
for (var i = 0; i < lenOfMenuBtn; i++) {
    menuBtn[i].addEventListener('click',addMenu,false) ;
}

function addMenu(e) {
    addOkFlag(e.target) ;
    // or addOkFlag(this);

}

function addOkFlag(el) {
    var elmnt = document.createElement('i');
    elmnt.setAttribute('class','glyphicon glyphicon-ok');
    el.appendChild(elmnt);
}
```

Comment: in `addMenu` can use `addOkFlag(this);`

Answer (score -1):

whatever you're trying to append to, give it an id attribute, then...

```
document.getElementsByClassName('myElementsId').appendChild(elmnt);
```

..replace "myElementsId" with your elements ID

Comment: i want to apply on multiple button so i use class instead of id

Comment: i probably should have read the code.. but you probably should have explained that too